# How do i flatten error messages to display a single consistent error message in Django?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am making a mobile app that uses Django Rest Framework.  When one of my models fails validation, it uses one of the model.attributes as a key inside the error message, for example:

```
{'status_code': 400, 'name': [u'Ensure this field has no more than 32 characters.']}
{'status_code': 400, 'password': [u'Ensure this field has no more than 32 characters.']}
{'status_code': 400, 'arbitrary_field': [u'Ensure this field has no more than 32 characters.']}
```

This is very difficult to scale in a mobile, so I want to take the error messages and deliver a consistent 'error' key to the mobile device. For example,

```
{'status_code': 400, 'error': [u' Name: Ensure this field has no more than 32 characters.']}
{'status_code': 400, 'error': [u'Password: Ensure this field has no more than 32 characters.']}
{'status_code': 400, 'error': [u'Arbitrary Field: Ensure this field has no more than 32 characters.']}
```

In Rails, I could do this by saying:

```
model.errors.full_messages
```

But I'm not sure what the equivalent in Django is?

Thanks

Comment: How should multiple errors for a particular field be formatted? For example: `{'field1': ['abc', 'xyz']}`

Comment: field1 - abc, field1 -xyz.  For the most part my errors are only single errors with single values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a property `custom_full_errors` in your serializer which will return the errors formatted according to your requirement. Doing `serializer.custom_full_errors` will give you the desired response.

We first call the `serializer.errors` to get the default `errors` dictionary. Then we iterate on this dictionary and create our desired response.

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    @property
    def custom_full_errors(self):
        """
        Returns full errors formatted as per requirements
        """
        default_errors = self.errors # default errors dict
        errors_messages = []
        for field_name, field_errors in default_errors.items():
            for field_error in field_errors:
                error_message = '%s: %s'%(field_name, field_error)
                errors_messages.append(error_message) # append error message to 'errors_messages'
        return {'error': errors_messages}

    ...
```

For example:

```
# serializer.errors 
{'name': [u'Ensure this field has no more than 32 characters.']}
```

will translate to

```
# serializer.custom_full_errors
{'error': [u'Name: Ensure this field has no more than 32 characters.']}
```

In case of multiple errors for a single field, we will get the following output on doing `serializer.custom_full_errors`:

```
# serializer.custom_full_errors
{'error': [u'Name: Error1', u'Name: Error2', u'Password: Error1', u'Password: Error2' ]}
```

Answer (score 1):

I read this blog article, am yet to test it out

https://masnun.com/2015/11/06/django-rest-framework-custom-exception-handler.html

You create a custom error handler that concatenates the key-value pairs, after passing the exception through the default error handler method

```
from rest_framework.views import exception_handler
  
def custom_exception_handler(exc, context):
    # Call REST framework's default exception handler first,
    # to get the standard error response.
    response = exception_handler(exc, context)
 
    if response is not None:
        data = response.data
        response.data = {}
        errors = []
        for field, value in data.items():
            errors.append("{} : {}".format(field, " ".join(value)))
 
        response.data['errors'] = errors
        response.data['status'] = False
 
        response.data['exception'] = str(exc)
 
    return response
```

Then you point DRF to your custom error handler

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ),
 
 
    'EXCEPTION_HANDLER': 'api.utils.custom_exception_handler'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In case somebody is still looking for a solution, here is a great library that helps a lot in dealing with custom error validation: https://pypi.org/project/drf-standardized-errors/, here is the GitHub repo: https://github.com/ghazi-git/drf-standardized-errors

The response will be flat and instead of this:

```
{
  "shipping_address": 
    {
      "non_field_errors": [ErrorDetail("We do not support shipping to the provided address.", code="unsupported")]
    }
}
```

You'll get this:

```
{
  "code": "unsupported",
  "detail": "We do not support shipping to the provided address.",
  "attr": "shipping_address.non_field_errors"
}
```

It deals pretty good with List Serializers, changing such response:

```
{
  "recipients": [
    {"name": [ErrorDetail("This field is required.", code="required")]},
    {"email": [ErrorDetail("Enter a valid email address.", code="invalid")]},
  ]
}
```

To this:

```
{
    "type": "validation_error",
    "errors": [
        {
            "code": "required",
            "detail": "This field is required.",
            "attr": "recipients.0.name"
        },
        {
            "code": "invalid",
            "detail": "Enter a valid email address.",
            "attr": "recipients.1.email"
        }
      ]
}
```

Based on this flat response it's much easier to form one string message to represent all the errors if you need to.
Basically, it handles the hardest part - getting a flat response out of a complex Django structure (all the nested fields, dicts, lists, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a bit late but I made this one using backtracking in case you have a lot of embedded nested serialisers.

```
from rest_framework.views import exception_handler


def custom_exception_handler(exc, context):
    # Call REST framework's default exception handler first,
    # to get the standard error response.
    response = exception_handler(exc, context)
    stack = [response.data]
    response.data = {}
    errors = {}

    if response is not None:
        while len(stack) > 0:
            data = stack.pop()
            for field, value in data.items():
                if type(value) is dict:
                    stack.append(value)
                else:
                    if value is not list:
                        errors[field] = value
                        continue

                    for val in value:

                        code = val.code
                        message = str(val)
                        errors[field] = {
                            'message': message,
                            'code': code
                            }

    response.data['errors'] = errors
    return response
```